# Visual Basic error when fields are left blank

Tags: vb.net

My form crashes when I go to debug it with the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

This is the code where I believe the issue is happening:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim decdays As Integer
    Dim decmedication As Decimal
    Dim decsurgical As Decimal
    Dim declabfee As Decimal
    Dim decphysical As Decimal
    Dim x As String
    TextBox1.Focus()
    decdays = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    decmedication = CDec(TextBox2.Text)
    decsurgical = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
    declabfee = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
    decphysical = CDec(TextBox5.Text)
    Dim charges As Decimal
    Dim totalMischarges As Decimal
    TextBox1.Focus()
    If decdays < 0 Then
        x = "Length of days should be numeric and positive"
        Label1.Text = x.ToString()
    ElseIf decmedication < 0 Then
        x = "Medication charges should be numeric and positive"
        Label2.Text = x.ToString()
    ElseIf decsurgical < 0 Then
        x = "Surgical charges should be numeric and positive"
        Label3.Text = x.ToString()
    ElseIf declabfee < 0 Then
        x = "Lab fees should be numeric and positive"
        Label4.Text = x.ToString()
    ElseIf decphysical < 0 Then
        x = "Physical charges should be numeric and positive"
        Label5.Text = x.ToString()
    Else
        charges = CalcStayCharges(decdays)
        totalMischarges = CalcMisCharges(decmedication, decsurgical, declabfee, decphysical)
        dectotalcost = CalcTotalCharges(charges, totalMischarges)
        TextBox6.Text = "$" + dectotalcost.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried a `TryParse()` but it isn't working!

Comment: If decdays < 0 Then... what? Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: `I tried a TryParse but it isn't working!` Then it seems like you posted the wrong non question

Comment: Okay I edited it to include the rest of the code.

Comment: what is the value in the textbox

Comment: If I don't put anything into the textbox it will crash, if I enter numbers the program works fine.

Comment: If you walk your code in debugger, you will immediately see your issue

Comment: An empty text box has a Text property of an empty string. An empty string cannot be converted to an integer or decimal. It is not zero, it is an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

All of these fields require a valid value in the text box for them to work. The error message is explaining the issue you are having.

If you text boxes can accept anything from the user, you should be validating your input before using it. If you use the `TryParse` pattern demonstrated below, it also sets the variables for use after validation.

These lines of code:

```
decdays = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
decmedication = CDec(TextBox2.Text)
decsurgical = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
declabfee = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
decphysical = CDec(TextBox5.Text)
```

Should be transformed into something like this:

```
Dim decdays As Integer
Dim decmedication As Decimal
Dim decsurgical As Decimal 
Dim declabfee As Decimal 
Dim decphysical As Decimal 

If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, decdays) Then
    messagebox.show("Textbox1 text is Not valid")
    Return
End If
If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, decmedication) Then
    messagebox.show("Textbox2 text is Not valid")
    Return
End If
If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, decsurgical) Then
    messagebox.show("Textbox3 text is Not valid")
    Return
End If
If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, declabfee) Then
    messagebox.show("Textbox4 text is Not valid")
    Return
End If
If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, decphysical) Then
    messagebox.show("Textbox5 text is Not valid")
    Return
End If
```

Comment: Nice demo of `TryParse.` Also the use of `Return` instead of the language specific `Exit Sub`  Together worth the upvote. You might mention to user that the TryParse will set the value of the variables if successful.